# splice() inside a for loop, what is the solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove repetitions from this array called "bigArray" while keeping the three first positions of the array intact (even if they repeat).

My issue is that the splice() inside the for loop is not working properly, since every time it splices, the for loop skips the next position of the array (since that position is then one position lower in the array).

**How do I get my function to return [0,0,0,3,2] ?**

Thank you

```js
var bigArray = [0,0,0,3,2,2,3,3,2];

function call() { 

  
  for (let i=3; i < (bigArray.length); i++) {
    if (bigArray.indexOf(bigArray[i]) !== i) {
          bigArray.splice(i,1);
    
    }

    }
    
    console.log(bigArray);
    return bigArray; 
}
    
call();
```

Comment: so you should not modify original array.. try use filter()

Comment: @guijob you can modify the original array, change only the iteration to be backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subtract i.

```js
var bigArray = [0,0,0,3,2,2,3,3,2];

function call() { 

  
  for (let i=3; i < (bigArray.length); i++) {
    if (bigArray.indexOf(bigArray[i]) !== i) {
          bigArray.splice(i,1);
       i--;
    }
  
  }
    
    console.log(bigArray);
    return bigArray; 
}
    
call();
```

Comment: Ohh... I didn't think about doing this simple thing!  But, why someone downvoted this solution?

Comment: Well, I don't know @Emilio. But this is simple. I hope this can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the array using splice() on which you are running the loop. you must use a second array to store non repeating values. you can do something like this:

```js
var bigArray = [0,0,0,3,2,2,3,3,2];
var noDuplicates = bigArray.slice(0,3);
function call() { 

  
  for (let i=3; i < (bigArray.length); i++) {
    if (bigArray.indexOf(bigArray[i]) === i) {
          noDuplicates.push(bigArray[i]);
    
    }

    }
    
    console.log(noDuplicates);
    return noDuplicates; 
}
    
call();
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way to do it.

```
    function finddup(arr){
      var tmp = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         if(i<3)
         {
          tmp.push(arr[i]);
         }
        else
        if(tmp.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)
         {
         tmp.push(arr[i]);
         }
     }
    return tmp; 
     }
```

Hope this help you !

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a functional approach:

```
var arr = [0,0,0,3,2,2,3,3,2];
arr.filter((e,i,self) => i<3 ? true : self.findIndex(x=>x === e) === i)
```